# Open a view that only changes based on the pin that you click?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, annotations, mkmapview

I have a problem that I do not know how to solve, I have a MapView with a series of Pin, if I click it gives me the information of local and when I click on the "i" should open a view with the information of it. The problem is this: if I wanted to open a view that changes depending on the Pin clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MKMapView` delegate method `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` gives you the `MKAnnotationView` object that has a property `annotation`, which itself has properties such an `title`, `subtitle`, and `coordinate`.
If this is not enough to identify your annotation, you could also subclass it and give it more properties.

Comment: Yes I know, but I would make a Main View that changes depending on the selected pin and not a single view for each pin. I do not know if I have explained

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right. I believe, you want essentially to do some action depending on the pin that was touched. But the pin was displayed because there was an annotation at this location. As soon as you know which annotation this was (see my answer above) you can do whatever you like in the method mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:.